# Problems with reading a txt file (EOF within quoted string)

Tags: r, file-io, read.table

I am trying to use `read.table()` to import [this `TXT` file](http://weather.noaa.gov/data/nsd_bbsss.txt) into `R` (contains informations about meteorological stations provided by the WMO):

However, when I try to use

```
tmp <- read.table(file=...,sep=";",header=FALSE)
```

I get this error

> eof within quoted string

warning and only 3514 of the 6702 lines appear in '`tmp`'. From a quick look at the text file, I couldn't find any seemingly problematic characters.

As suggested in other threads, I also tried `quote=""`. The `EOF` warning disappeared, but still only 3514 lines are imported.

Any advice on how I can get `read.table()` to work for this particular txt file?

Comment: ...just so you know, the issue is that some fields have unmatched double quotes. See line 2808.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like your data actually has 11548 rows. This works:

```
read.table(url('http://weather.noaa.gov/data/nsd_bbsss.txt'), 
    sep=';', quote=NULL, comment='', header=FALSE)
```

**edit:** updated according @MrFlick's comment's below.

Comment: Actually, you'll want to set `comment=""` as well. Then you won't need the `fill=TRUE` (you're actually dropping information if you do that.)

Comment: indeed! I didn't notice there are "#" in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is LF. R will not recognize "^M", to load the file, you only need to specify the encoding like this:

```
read.table("nsd_bbsss.txt",sep=";",header=F,encoding="latin1",quote="",comment='',colClasses=rep("character",14)) -> data
```

But Line 8638 has more than 14 columns, which is different from other lines and may lead an error message.