# Text-Mining "In scan: EOF within quoted string" error

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, pdftotext

I need to convert 24 PDF files in a folder into txt files so that I can perform semantic analysis on them. I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445659/use-r-to-convert-pdf-files-to-text-files-for-text-mining) question, and proceeded from there. However, after getting the code to work the first time, I then changed some things around, and now I am getting the following error:

```
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  EOF within quoted string
```

Because of this, what is saved in the `bodies` variable in the code below is just a list of 24 blanks, and I end up with 24 blank text files (in addition to the 24 text files that are created by converting the PDFs into txt). I'm not sure what I've done wrong - at one point, this code worked!

I've already looked through what I could find about this error, but those are associated with `read.csv`, and the fixes they suggested (setting `white.space=TRUE` and `quote=""`) did not work.

Here's the code (the error is on line 20-23):

```
# folder with journal articles
PDFfolder_path <- "~/Dropbox/The Egoist PDFs/PDFs"
# vector of PDF file names
PDFfiles <- list.files(path=PDFfolder_path, pattern="*.pdf", full.names=TRUE)
# location of pdftotext.exe file
converter <- "~/Widgets/PDFConverter/bin64/pdftotext"
# folder with text files
textfolder_path <- "~/Dropbox/The Egoist PDFs/textfiles"

# convert PDFs in origin folder into txt files
lapply(PDFfiles, function(i) {
  system(paste(converter, paste0('"', i, '"')), wait=FALSE)
})
# it takes DropBox a bit of time to catch all of the folders
# without this we only end up with 23 txt files for some reason
Sys.sleep(.5)
txtfiles_in_PDFfolder_path <- list.files(path=PDFfolder_path, pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE)

# extracting only the Bodies of the articles
bodies <- lapply(txtfiles_in_PDFfolder_path, function(i){
  j <- paste0(scan(i, what = character()),  collapse = " ")
  regmatches(j, gregexpr("(?<=Published).*?(?=Prepaid Advertisements)", j, perl=TRUE))
})

# write article-bodies into txt files
lapply(1:length(bodies), function(i){
  write.table(bodies[i], file=paste(txtfiles_in_PDFfolder_path[i], "body", "txt", sep="."), quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, eol=" ")
})
```

EDIT: A bit more on the result of the `bodies` variable: the result is a list of 24, which takes the following form (on the R Studio console, I'm not sure the actual name of this): 
    bodies: list of 24
       :List of 1
        ..$ : chr(0)
       :List of 1
        ..$ : chr(0)
(repeating 24 times)

But I can't for the life of me figure out why it's `chr(0)` - I think it has something to do with the same kind of things that's going on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679042/problems-with-reading-a-txt-file-eof-within-quoted-string) - I'm definitely not capturing all of the lines.

I've tried everything I can think of, even switching `readLines()` for `scan()`, and I've looked to see if that might help. I've even switched `scan()` for `read.table()`, but it turns out that `read.table()` itself relies on `scan`! So... I'm stuck, and am just working my way in circles.

Comment: Does this happen with one PDF in particular? (try them each separately).  Have you inspected the contents of your converted files? Without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) it will be very difficult to help you.

Comment: It happens for every PDF. And I've looked through the contents for the converted files, but they're relatively long, and I'm not sure what to look for. But I made a pastebin for one of the converted documents, hopefully that will help!

http://pastebin.com/dDfzJC91

Comment: Well, it sure sounds like there is bad data in the converted text files. Unless you can extract a portion that reproduces this behavior, it's very difficult to tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you need `scan()` rather than `readLines()`? (Note they do return different vectors but it doesn't seem like you need to break by word)

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'll try to find a portion that causes this to happen. However, at one point this was working fine - when the code was going well, R converted and cut the txt files perfectly well (and very quickly). But then I changed something (not at all sure what) and for each files R started to say things like `Read 10648 items`, and began to take noticeably longer.

Comment: Progress! When I changed to `readLines( )`, I get `Warning message:
In readLines(i) :
  incomplete final line found on '/Users/mlinegar/Dropbox/The Egoist PDFs/PDFs/The Egoist 2.1.1914.txt'`.

But I'm not sure what would cause an incomplete final line... any ideas?